# Google Geocode API - Postal Code not returned

Tags: json, google-maps

I have a site that validates zip codes.  If a user types in a zip code I store the formatted address, lat, long, etc.  If they go back in to edit the form the next day, I set the field to the formatted address and revalidate.  The problem is not all formatted addresses return the zip the second time - even though I'm passing it in to the query.

-- RETURNS FORMATTED ADDRESS: Woodland, CA 95776, USA
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=95776&key=

-- DOESN'T RETURN A POSTAL CODE - GIVES APPROXIMATE EVEN THOUGH I'M PASSING IT IN
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Woodland, CA 95776, USA&key=

-- RETURNS POSTAL CODE AS EXPECTED, EVEN THOUGH LENEXA, HAS MULTIPLE POSTAL CODES
/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Lenexa, KS 66227, USA&key=

Comment: Looks like this is a familiar issue [Why does Google GeoCoding only sometimes return the postal code?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13993474/1248974), [Google Map V3 Postal Code not returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490851/google-map-v3-postal-code-not-returned#comment30628750_20490851), and [Google Maps API sometimes not returning PostalCode within AddressDetails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3491048/1248974)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest storing the place ID instead of the address string. This is recommended by Google:

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/place-id#save-id

So the first time you execute

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=95776&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

and store the resulting place ID `ChIJARdFFWLRhIARK6RIUxEbJ30`.

The next time you should execute the place ID lookup to get exactly the same result as the original request

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?place_id=ChIJARdFFWLRhIARK6RIUxEbJ30&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Comment: This is a great idea. I thought of it too and am doing this, HOWEVER, the question is how to return the postal code. This is aesthetic. Yes we would be delivering real map locations and directions with the ID as you stated BUT what if we want to display, visually, the postal code?